# How do I just get the first matching row?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a fairly complex SQL query - part of which requires to look up a company_ID value found in the first table to obtain the company_Name in the second table. The second table may have variants of the company name, but that is OK - I just need the first match.

So, tableA looks something like this (approx 2 dozen columns and many rows)

```
company_ID (CHAR(12))
161012348876
561254435253
103929478273
141567643542
```

tableB looks something like this

```
company_ID (Integer) Company_name
161012348876         Watson & Jones Ltd
161012348876         Watson and Jones
561254435253         Fictional Co. plc
103929478273         Made Up Corp.
161012348876         Watson Jones Ltd
141567643542         Thingymajig Gmbh.
```

This query will return multiple rows for 161012348876. What're good ways just to get one row returned for each matching company_id (i.e. 4 rows instead of 6)?

```
SELECT *, t2.company_name
FROM tableA t1

JOIN tableB t2 ON t1.company_id = cast(t2.company_id as CHAR(12))
```

I am using Teradata SQL.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *, t2.company_name
FROM tableA t1

JOIN tableB t2 ON t1.company_id = cast(t2.company_id as CHAR(12))
GROUP BY t1.company_id
```

Will return 1 row for each unique `t1.company_id`

Comment: I think the OP wants to get the `TOP 1` for each value in TableA.

Comment: That's correct. For each company_id in tableA I want a matching company_name from tableB.

Answer (score 1):

The following query will get one Name for each company id. The `Group by t2.company_id` and `MAX(t2.company_name)` will get a unique name for each id and then join it with `tableA`.

```
SELECT t1.Company_ID, t2.company_name
FROM tableA t1
    JOIN (SELECT t2.company_id , MAX(t2.company_Name) [aName] 
          FROM tableB t2 GROUP BY t2.company_id ) as t3
        ON t1.company_id = cast(t3.company_id as CHAR(12))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of user2989408's MAX subquery you can also do a

```
SELECT company_id , company_Name 
FROM tableB
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY company_name) = 1

--if you don't care about MIN/MAX or want a more random result:
QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY company_id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) = 1
```

But assuming that *company_id* is the PI of tableB the MAX will probably perform better.